# Codility Flags, almost perfect, can't understand which edge case is the cause of failure

Tags: javascript, algorithm

You can see the task text here: https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/8/

This is my solution:

```
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// console.log('this is a debug message');

function solution(A) {
var length = A.length,
peaksIndex = [];
for (var i=1;i<length-1;i++){
    if (A[i] > A[i-1] && A[i] > A[i+1]){
        peaksIndex.push(i);
    }
}
var peaksLength = peaksIndex.length;
var maxPeaksLength = Math.min(Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(length)), peaksLength);
var maxFound = 0;
for (var j=maxPeaksLength;j>0;j--){
    //debugger;
    // j is the max number of flags AND distance
    var found = 0;
    var distance = 0;
    for (var k=peaksLength-1;k>=0;k--){
        var prevPeak;
        if (k===0){
            prevPeak = -j;
        } else {
            prevPeak = peaksIndex[k-1];
        }
        distance += peaksIndex[k]-prevPeak;
        if (distance >=j){
            distance = 0;
            found++;
        }
    }
    if (found > maxFound) {
        maxFound = found;
    }
    if (maxFound >= j-1){
        break;
    }
}
return maxFound;
// write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 4.0.0)
}
```

or on Codility: https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingQJNNVS-U3Y/

As you can see there, the only incorrect case is

> large_anti_slow
> large test anti slow
> solutions WRONG ANSWER  got 317, expected 316
>
> 1. 0.298 s OK
> 2. 0.216 s WRONG ANSWER,  got 317 expected 316

In short, I don't understand what's problematic in my algorithm that it fails only in this single case?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you wouldn't be interested in this anymore but I got the exact same result strangely: https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingSCRPHX-K4N/

Answer (score 1):

After having the same test error when submitting Python code I contacted Codility and the failing test 'large_anti_slow' looks like this:

```
[0, 1] * 50000
```

You can use a shorter version of the test, with a factor of 10 instead:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

The code should return **4** with this array, your code returns **5**.

I patched the code in your last "for" loop, changing this part:

```
        if (distance >=j){
            distance = 0;
            found++;
        }
```

To this:

```
        if (distance >=j){
            distance = 0;
            found++;
            if (found == j){
                return found;
            }
        }
```

The result:
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingXCGTSB-WKQ/

In summary; the code needs to check when square root of total flag distance is reached, placing additional flags at this point would change the distance.

Answer (score 0):

The order of iteration over k looks a bit weird.  From the contents of the loop it looks like you wanted to start with k==0, but the loop actually goes in descending order.

It may work better if you change:

```
for (var k=peaksLength-1;k>=0;k--){
```

into

```
for (var k=0;k<=peaksLength-1;k++){
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure what would change, the same numbers are being iterated - I've tried anyway, same result (error); thanks for trying!

Comment: Oh well, what I expected to change was the value of distance during the iteration (as it depends on the previous value so I believe it should make a difference which direction is iterated).